# Annotation Format for Entity Relation Extractor in Spacy NER

Tags: spacy, data-annotations, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to get relation between entities for the model which we have already built for NER using spacy. I was able to find relation_extractor trainable component to get the relationship among the entities.

I am very new to relation_extractor and was able to understand how to train the data. But unfortunately I was not able to find the format needed for annotation and couldn't find any resources as well. Could someone help me with the format for annotation data. Would be really helpful.

Documentation referred: https://spacy.io/usage/layers-architectures#components

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The [relation extractor component example project](https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/v3/tutorials/rel_component) includes code for creating training data for the component. The process is also explained in the accompanying video.

Answer (score 0):

This video https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/v3/tutorials/rel_component is just telling you how to use the components to build the relation_extractor without telling you how to create the entity-relation training data. In this video, the lady only mentioned they used the gold-standard annotation training data, which means it was annotated manually.